# General solution for $\frac{\mathrm{d}^2 y}{\mathrm{d} x^2} = y$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, trigonometry, exponential-function

Start with

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}^2 y}{\mathrm{d} x^2} = y$$

then

$$\frac{1}{\mathrm{d} x} \, \mathrm{d} \left(\frac{\mathrm{d} y }{\mathrm{d} x}\right) = y$$

$$\frac{\mathrm{d} y}{\mathrm{d} x} \, \mathrm{d} \left(\frac{\mathrm{d} y }{\mathrm{d} x}\right) = y \, \mathrm{d} y$$

$$\frac{\mathrm{d} y}{\mathrm{d} x}  = \sqrt{y^2 + c}$$

$$\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{y^2+c}} \mathrm{d} y = x + c_1$$

$$ \ln\left(\sqrt{y^2 +c_0} + y\right) = x + c_1$$
$$ \sqrt{y^2 +c_0} + y = e^{x + c_1}$$

This does look trigonometric and exponential as it should but I don't know how to proceed to simplify it.

I actually know the actual solution but I want to prove it from first principles. This means I don't want to use guess and check methods because they can't handle solving problems in general and I don't want to assume the result in order to prove it.

Comment: No clue what your first manipulation is supposed to mean. The routine solution is to assume that $y=e^{cx}$ and then conclude that $c^2=1$, so $c=\pm 1$. By linear ODE theory, all solutions are linear combinations of these two.

Comment: Off the bat, the e-power function is a solution to your DFQ, but I truly wonder if the e-power is represented by your solution

Comment: Not sure on the validity of your steps, but if you're just looking for how to solve for $y$ in your last equation, you can subtract $y$ from both sides to isolate the radical, square both sides, and then you can bring all the terms to one side, leaving the other side as zero. This will leave you with a quadratic in terms of $y$ which you can solve with the quadratic formula

Answer (score 4):

You are over complicating.

Re-write it as $y'' - y = 0$. Then it has auxiliary equation $\lambda^2 - 1 = 0$. So the general solution is $y = \alpha e^{x} + \beta e^{-x}$.

Answer (score 2):

It does look like trigonometric and exponential function indeed:

The characteristic equation is $\lambda^2-1=0$, with roots $\pm1$, hence a basis of the space of solutions is $\mathrm e^x$ and  $\mathrm e^{-x}$, or if one prefers
$$\frac{\mathrm e^x+\mathrm e^{-x}}2=\cosh x,\qquad \frac{\mathrm e^x-\mathrm e^{-x}}2=\sinh x.$$

For the analogy to  be complete, the *harmonic oscillator* equation $\; y''=-y\;$ has characteristic equation $\lambda^2+1=0$, with roots $\pm\mathrm i$, hence a basis of the space of solutions is $\mathrm e^{\mathrm i x}$ and  $\mathrm e^{-\mathrm i x}$, or
$$\frac{\mathrm e^{\mathrm i x}+\mathrm e^{-\mathrm i x}}2=\cos  x,\qquad \frac{\mathrm e^{\mathrm i x}-\mathrm e^{-\mathrm i x}}{2\mathrm i}=\sin  x.$$

Answer (score 2):

For linear equations with constant coefficients, the "guess-and-check" method, which amounts to assuming $y=e^{\lambda x}$ and solving for $\lambda$, actually does generalize to all possibilities (provided that you can solve the necessary equation for $\lambda$, and with appropriate adjustment for duplicate roots). One can also prove using general linear ODE theory that it doesn't miss any solutions.

That said, if you want to do it without this, one way is operator factorization: $y''-y=0$ is the same as $(D^2-1)y=0$ which is the same as $(D+1)(D-1)y=0$. You can do this by finding the general solution $z$ to $(D+1)y=0$ (i.e. $y'+y=0$) and then solving $(D-1)y=z$. Each of these can be solved using the integrating factor technique. (Of course in a way the integrating factor technique is *itself* guess-and-check...)

Comment: Finally I see the only solution that **explains** how to get the general solution other than by saying without justification "the characteristic equation is ... so the general solution is ..."

Answer (score 2):

Your approach is a slightly garbled version of a perfectly fine *heuristic* (which then is easily checked to have produced genuine solutions):

From $y''=y$, get ${d\over dx}(y')=y$ as you do, then, one way or another, multiply through by $dy$ as you do, to get $y'\,dy'=y\,dy$. It is at this point that you made some manipulation errors, because one would (at least heuristically) get ${1\over 2}(y')^2={1\over 2}y^2+C$. Taking $C=0$, we can easily take the square root(s): $y'=\pm y$, then $dy/y=\pm d$, or $\log y=\pm x+C$. Exponentiating, $y=e^{\pm x}$, which gives the two solutions we knew all along.

This kind of manipulation does appear in many older differential equations sources, and does give a way to anticipate the solutions (without having to know the constant-coefficient equation riff, as standard and basic as the latter is).

EDIT: after @Ian's and Willie Wong's comments... Indeed, taking $C=1$, for example, instead of $0$, gives $\int \sqrt{1+y^2}\;dy=x$, which is easily solved by letting $y=(t+t^{-1})/2$ (although knowing such a trick is perhaps already contrary to the spirit?)...

2nd EDIT: and, also, "discovering" the solutions via a non-linear differential equation (as a result of the manipulation) does create hazards that linear equations don't share, e.g., that solutions don't necessarily add... :)

Comment: Why take $C=0$? The rest is fine, but this assumption seems to be unjustified. Without this assumption $C$ is still arbitrary, and in fact the "obvious" solutions $e^{\pm x}$ don't satisfy, say, $y'=\sqrt{y^2+1}$.

Comment: @Ian, indeed, it's unclear what this heuristic really means, which is why I don't wish to worry about it as anything other than a heuristic. I vaguely recall that some version can be made at least _more_ rigorous, if not really rigorous, but perhaps it's not worth the effort. That is, it's a useful _discovery_ method, if supported by other devices. To my mind, "discovery", even if non-rigorous or only good half-the-time, is still valuable.

Comment: @Ian Actually, noting that $\cosh$ and $\sinh$ are also solutions to the original ODE, you have solutions of the form $(y')^2 - y^2 = \pm 1$. And then by scaling you get all $C$. You should NOT set $C$ to zero....

Comment: If you want to be fancy, you can consider writing it in "conservation law" form: $y'^2+\left ( \frac{y}{i} \right )^2=C$ where $C$ is some complex constant. With a bit of thought you get to something that looks much like the harmonic oscillator but some $i$'s sprinkled about, and some standard complex analysis reveals the exponential solutions.

Comment: @WillieWong Indeed, I noticed this just now from my different perspective. So now I guess the question is: how to solve $y'=\pm \sqrt{y^2+c}$ where $c$ is arbitrary? This can be done by separation of variables but the difficulty of the resulting integral (unless you are familiar with the inverse hyperbolic substitutions) is a bit excessive...

Comment: We can make it rigorous by first developing a theory of differentiation of arbitrary variables parametrized by a separate parameter $t$, so that $\frac{dy}{dx}$ is defined as the limit of $\frac{Δy}{Δx}$ as $Δt \to 0$ if it exists. This creates symmetry between the variables and allows a rigorous but intuitive derivation of various results. Here for example $\frac{dy'}{dx} = y$ where $y' = \frac{dy}{dx}$. Thus $\frac{dy'}{dy} y' = y y'$ and so $\frac12 \frac{d(y'^2)}{dy} = \frac12 \frac{d(y^2)}{dy}$, giving $y'^2 = y^2 + c$ for some constant $c$.

Answer (score 1):

Your first manipulation is incorrect. Something like this is true:

$\frac{d}{dx} \frac{dy}{dx} = y$

But this doesn't help you. 
A common method for solving this is to look at it as two applications of the derivative-with-respect-to-x operator:

$\frac{d}{dx} \frac{d}{dx} y = y$
Let $D = \frac{d}{dx}$, then the above is equivalent to $(D^2 - 1)y = 0$ (we moved the sole $y$ to the left hand side). Factoring the expression gives us:
$(D-1)(D+1)y = 0$. The general solution is a linear combination of the solutions of $(D+1)y = 0$ or $(D-1)y = 0$. Well the first equation is just $y'=-y$ and its solution is $e^-x$, the second option is $y' = y$ and hence has the solution $e^x$. The general solution is thus $y(x) = c_1 e^{-x} + c_2 e^x$ for some $c_1,c_2 \in \mathbb R$.

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%27%27+%3D+y

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to solve $$y''=y.$$

Rewrite the equation as

$$y''+y'-y' -y=0.$$

This is just

$$y''+y'-1(y'+y)=0.$$

Let $z=y'+y.$

The equation now becomes

$$z'-z=0$$

This has solution $z=Ce^x$ with $C$ being a constant. Verify this using separation of variables.

Now we solve $$Ce^x=y'+y$$

Using the integrating factor method,

$$y=\frac{\int \mu(x)Ce^x dx+ D}{\mu(x)}$$, where $D$ is a constant and

$\mu(x)=e^{\int 1 dx}=e^x$

This tells us that:

$$y=\frac{\frac{Ce^{2x}}{2}+D}{e^x}=Ee^x+De^{-x}$$ where $E$ is a constant.

Comment: This is just operator factorization in disguise; I mentioned operator factorization in my answer.